Is there any kind of permission in AOSP to use classes from other modules?
I'm going to modify the AOSP to meet the requirements.
I'm trying to create setStatus(int), getStatus() by creating (example field value) mStatus in LinkProperties class in Connectivity module in package/module.
However, if you create a LinkProperties object in the NetworkStack module and use the method, a symbol not found error occurs.
For your information, I updated the current.txt file using the m command.
Any great developers who have had similar experiences?
Have a nice day, thank you :)
packages/modules/NetworkStack/src/android/net/ip/IpClient.java: error: cannot find symbol
        newLp.setNetworkStatus(mNetworkStatus);
             ^
  symbol:   method setNetworkStatus(int)
  location: variable newLp of type LinkProperties

